# pfSense: Captive portal auth via Active Directory (2003)

Tags: active-directory, pfsense

I'm trying to set up a new firewall server. We chose pfSense and it's working nicely so far.
We managed to our Windows Server 2003 Active Directory as a user Authentication Server (System -> User Manager -> Servers). And it tests OK. Then we selected this AD server as the authentication server in User manager -> Settings.
However, when we setup a Captive Portal, we cannot use this AD server to authenticate users there.
I read that we should use RADIUS, but is there any other way using LDAP?
Thanks